# How much is sharepoint licence cost

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

How much is the SharePoint server cost.
It can be yearly renewals or one time payment

Please provide info

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of factor involves in getting the final cost.

Internal users will require a CAL which is about $100 per user.
A forecast of the number of users will be used for Capacity planning for your SharePoint farm. Each server will require a server license. So the number of users may increase the cost of the server licensing.

Each server will require a SharePoint server license. These are typically one-time licenses that cost around $7,000 per server. You will not need a SharePoint license for the server running SQL server.

If you are planning a project or solution that uses SharePoint 2013 Enterprise features, additional Enterprise CALs will be needed for users leveraging them. This increases the one-time cost for internal users by about 90% per user.

More details can be found - http://www.degdigital.com/archives/1500

https://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview

[image]

If you choose SharePoint Foundation then you’re done. You pay $0 for the server license and $0 for an infinite number of users.

If you Choose SharePoint Server then you have to ask how many servers do you need in your farm. One server is the least you can choose, but if you want to scale better and get better performance (maybe for production environments) then you’ll need more than one.

If you need 4 servers then the total will be: `4 * $5,000 = $20,000.00`

Atop of this cost is the cost of the user licenses. If you have 100 Enterprise users (meaning 100 users accessing the SharePoint Enterprise Edition), then the total for those CALs is: `100 * $180 = 18,000.00`

[image]

Source - http://www.portalfronthosting.com/blog/how-much-does-a-sharepoint-license-cost

Comment: Explanation is really nice but when I am trying to open http://www.portalfronthosting.com/blog/how-much-does-a-sharepoint-license-cost link it is automatically redirecting to https://www.portalfronthosting.com/hosted-sharepoint-plans.html I am not able to read the content of link.

Comment: Amal,
Are the SharePoint Server License and Standard CAL License one time or yearly?

Answer (score 1):

VLA SHAREPOINT SERVER 2019 $4,767.29

VLA SHAREPOINT STD PER USER CAL 2019 $86.10 each

VLA SQL SERVER STD PER 2 CORE LIC 2019 qty2 $4,571.30

Comment: John, could you please provide proof link?