# Installation of Sharepoint Web Front End Server

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, wfe

I am trying to add one Web Front end server to my existing SharePoint farm enterprise edition.
Can I use a SharePoint foundation as an additional web front end server to my existing far or do I need to purchase additional license for SharePoint server enterprise edition to setup an additional WFE.
Please you can also add download links.

Answer (score 1):

Edition mixes are not supported. You won't be able to join the server to the farm. So you have to install an Enterprise Edition Server, join it to the farm and give it the according roles like WFE.

If Enterprise is too expensive for you and you do not need the Enterprise-Features on a wide audience of users, you might have a look here: [SharePoint 2013 Downgrade from Enterprise to Standard](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192594/sharepoint-2013-downgrade-from-enterprise-to-standard)

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Does it mean that If I need to install 4 web front end server i would need to acquire 4 additional SharePoint license?

Comment: Yes, you need to buy those 4 SharePoint Server Licenses. The question is: Do you really need to upgrade by 4 additional servers? Those can handle a LOT of load.

Answer (score 1):

1. I am afraid you won't be able to join the SharePoint foundation server as an additional WFE to your existing enterprise edition SharePoint farm, as they are 2 different builds.
2. Cost of additional license depends on your SharePoint farm scenarios like Intranet, Extranet or Internet applications. For more information about licensing cost you can ref to the following links.
   [How much is sharePoint licence cost](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138515/how-much-is-sharepoint-licence-cost) and [SharePoint 2019 licensing](https://www.microsoft.com/en/microsoft-365/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview)
3. For accurate information on pricing please get in touch with your Microsoft account manager.